# How should I use the word, “mean” in a question when regarding about the past?

Tags: tense, rhetorical-questions

I’m writing an essay about how I thought I was as a kid and I’m starting off with a particular question, but I’m stuck in what tense the word, “mean” should be in.

Should the sentence be...
“Did I know what the word, ‘love’ mean?”,
“Did I know what the word, ‘love’ means?”,
or “Did I know what the word, ‘love’ meant?”

Comment: Why not just put "Did I know the meaning of the word love"? Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the verb tense of the sub-clause *what the word, ‘love’ **means** / **meant*** is the same as, for example, *He told me his name **is** / **was** Mr Smith*, so you'll often see the usage described as [backshifting of reported speech](https://www.englishgrammar.org/reported-speech-backshifting/) - but it can apply in other contexts besides reported speech.

I should point out first of all that the "subject" of the clause *(the word, ‘love’)* is *singular*, so the Present Tense verb form must be ***means***, not ***mean***.

Whether to use Present Tense ***means*** or Past Tense ***meant*** is to some extent a stylistic choice, but *usually* we do "backshift" the verb in the sub-clause, to match the Past Tense verb in the main clause (OP's ***Did*** I know, and *He **told** me* in my example above).

You'll sometimes hear people saying that you should use Present Tense if the sub-clause refers to something that is *still* true (if I knew what 'love' meant before, I still do; if his name was Smith, it still is). But that can be a bit misleading. It would be more accurate to say you *shouldn't* use Present Tense if the subclause refers to something that's *no longer true*. Consider...

> *When I saw him yesterday...*
>    1: *...he told me he is upset*
>    2: *...he told me he was upset*
>    3: *...he told me he is hungry*
>    4: *...he told me he was hungry*

Most native speakers would almost always use the Past Tense versions #2 and #4, but it certainly wouldn't always be "wrong" to use Present Tense in #1 - a "careful" speaker might deliberately do this to emphasise the fact that the person being spoken of is ***still*** upset.

We could in principle contrive a somewhat metaphorical context where ***hungry*** meant something like ***hungry for power***, in which case even my example #3 could be validly used. But I will admit that one is rather unlikely - taken at face value, most people wouldn't accept #3 as valid.

---

In short, you won't go far wrong if you *always* backshift in constructions like this, but you shouldn't assume this is an absolute rule.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about when you were a kid, which is in the past, it should be “Did I know what the word, ‘love’ meant?”.

However, “Did I know what the word, ‘love’ means?” is also correct and can be used, depending on the narration and flow of your essay.

But definitely not “Did I know what the word, ‘love’ mean?”. This is grammatically wrong.